# promise is not resolved although it gets awaited

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to get the pixels from some images and return them as an array. For the image handling I use https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp . Jimp has an asynchronous function `jimp.read(filePath)` that needs to get handled with await. My image reader module:

```
const config = require('./configuration.json');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const jimp = require('jimp');

module.exports = readImages;

function readImages() { // Reads the image files and extracts the colors
    const files = getFilesFromDirectory();
    const imageFiles = filterForImageFiles(files);
    return getInformationFromImageFiles(imageFiles);
}

function getFilesFromDirectory() { // Reads all the files from the directory provided from the configuration file
    return fs.readdirSync(config.dirPath);
}

function filterForImageFiles(files) { // Filters an array of files for .png and .jpg files
    return files.filter(file => {
        const fileExtension = path.extname(file);
        const isPngFile = fileExtension === '.jpg';
        const isJpgFile = fileExtension === '.png';
        return isPngFile || isJpgFile;
    });
}

function getInformationFromImageFiles(imageFiles) { // Maps image files to image information
    return imageFiles.map(imageFile => getInformationFromImageFile(imageFile));
}

async function getInformationFromImageFile(imageFile) { // Extracts information from an image file
    const filePath = path.join(config.dirPath, imageFile);
    const image = await jimp.read(filePath);
    return getColorsFromImage(image);
}

function getColorsFromImage(image) { // Extracts the colors from an image file
    const { width, height } = image.bitmap;
    const colors = [,];
    for (let x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        for (let y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            const intColor = image.getPixelColor(x, y);
            const rgbaColor = jimp.intToRGBA(intColor);
            colors[x, y] = rgbaColor;
        }
    }
    return colors;
}
```

When I run the code I receive an array with two items (because I provided two images). Both are `Promise { <pending> }`. Please have a look at `getInformationFromImageFile` which is an `async` function awaiting the jimp reader.

Why does it return a promise and does not resolve it? Do I have to await every function and the whole module ... ?

Comment: `await jimp.read(filePath)` does work, and it is waiting for the call to resolve. However you're not awaiting the call to `getInformationFromImageFile(imageFile)` in `getInformationFromImageFiles`.

Comment: What do you want `readImages` to return?

Comment: an array of image files

Comment: @Olian04 sorry, I still get the Promise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `getInformationFromImageFile` is marked `async` it will return a `Promise` therefore it must be awaited. You need to `await` where it is called. These changes should fix it:

```js
async function getInformationFromImageFiles(imageFiles) {
    const imageInfos = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < imageFiles.length; i++) {
        const imageFile = imageFiles[i];
        imageInfos.push(await getInformationFromImageFile(imageFile));
    }

    return imageInfos;
}

async function readImages() {
    const files = getFilesFromDirectory();
    const imageFiles = filterForImageFiles(files);
    return await getInformationFromImageFiles(imageFiles);
}
```

Comment: Yes sorry my bad @MarkMeyer, have edited the answer and hopefully it's correct now.

Comment: sorry but I still get a Promise

Comment: @Question3r When calling `readImages` you will need to await (or use 'then' syntax) as this is now async so will return a Promise. Do you await `readImages`?

Comment: ah, thanks, now it works. But please update your `getInformationFromImageFiles(imageFiles)` function, `imageFiles.push` should be `imageInfos.push` to make it work :)

Answer (score 0):

You also need to `await` the function `getInformationFromImageFile()`.

Comment: sorry, I still get the Promise

Answer (score 0):

`async/await` is just like promises. You gotta handle your async returns like you handle promises.

**Whenever you invoke an async function, you gotta await it in another async function or use `.then()` like you do with promises.**

```
// make this function async
async function readImages() {
  // Reads the image files and extracts the colors
  const files = getFilesFromDirectory();
  const imageFiles = filterForImageFiles(files);
  // the next line is an async call - so await it
  const images = await getInformationFromImageFiles(imageFiles); // array of images
  return images;
}

function getFilesFromDirectory() {
  // Reads all the files from the directory provided from the configuration file
  return fs.readdirSync(config.dirPath);
}

function filterForImageFiles(files) {
  // Filters an array of files for .png and .jpg files
  return files.filter((file) => {
    const fileExtension = path.extname(file);
    const isPngFile = fileExtension === '.jpg';
    const isJpgFile = fileExtension === '.png';
    return isPngFile || isJpgFile;
  });
}

// make this function async
async function getInformationFromImageFiles(imageFiles) {
  // promisify all async returns
  return Promise.all(imageFiles.map((imageFile) => getInformationFromImageFile(imageFile)));
}

// return async
async function getInformationFromImageFile(imageFile) {
  // Extracts information from an image file
  const filePath = path.join(config.dirPath, imageFile);
  const image = await jimp.read(filePath);
  return getColorsFromImage(image);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Async/Await always returns Promise, so you can do something like this:

```
Promise
  .all(readImages())
  .then(imd => console.log(imd))
  .catch(error => console.log(error));`
```

Answer (score -1):

As other member said, your function needs to be `awaited` hence it will return the promise `result`.

If you want to avoid `awaiting` the function, you can get your promise result in a synchronous way, like this:

```
let x = new Promise(function(){
//code
});
x.then(function(data){
   //Promise resolved, do something
}).then(function(err){
   //Promise rejected, do something
});
```